# Two (or more) LRU caches for a Node.js app

Tags: object-oriented, node.js, cache, typescript

Here is a caching code of a nodejs / typescript app using lru Cache module from https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache.
For various reason i need to setup separate caches: one for homeCache another one for detailThreadCache... but this is just the beginning I may need to set up more.

This code is working, but how would you refactor it to improve code reuse ? Would you use object oriented paradigm ? If yes how ?

```
const homeCache = lruCache( 50 )
const detailThreadCache = lruCache( 150 )

export function homeCachedData( key ) {
    return homeCache.get( key )
}

export function homeSetCache( key: string, value, duration: number ) {
    homeCache.set( key, value, duration )
}

export function detailThreadGetCache( key ) {
    return detailThreadCache.get( key )
}

export function detailThreadSetCache( key: string, value, duration: number ) {
    detailThreadCache.set( key, value, duration )
}
```

Comment: There is more than one LRU cache module available for Node.js. Please be specific. Also, it would be a good idea to add some context about how you are using these functions. At first glance, I would suggest just getting rid of all four functions.

Comment: I added link to the lru module in question. Would be very curious to see how you would replace the functions, while still allowing use of several different caches.

Comment: Like I said, just get rid of them, period. If you want to see specific examples of how to do that, then show your code. Otherwise, you're just asking for code to be written rather than asking for a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, remove the functions. Don't even go into OOP. As to why, they're simply unnecessary wrappers to your cache objects which you can just access directly. `detailThreadCache.set` is just as verbose as `detailThreadSetCache`.

Improving code doesn't necessarily mean reuse or encapsulation or a paradigm shift. Often times, the best code... is the one that's never written.

Comment: Ok I see what they meant when they recommended to remove the functions.But what if I decide in the future to replace leru memory cache with redis ? With the wrapper I would only change the cache file and not the places where the functions are called. Wouldn't it be worth it ?

Comment: @RobertBrax But that remains to be seen, a "what if". [Analysis paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) is real. Focus on your app, worry when you get there. Regardless of the presence an abstraction layer, a switch in dependency will almost always involve a significant rewrite. It's never a "swap out and it will just work".

Comment: Indeed, I removed the file, and made direct call to the cache module. Result: I eliminated an entire file, and simplified the problem of the different caches, since each call is on a different file with its own variable storage. Also you are so right, it's never a "swap and it will work" anyway.